# Не могу понять из-за чего падает android приложение

Tags: android

У меня есть два поля для ввода текста и два поля для отображения. По нажатию на кнопку я хочу передавать текст через собственный класс. Приложение падает еще не запустившись.

Код активити:

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.classes.List_v2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView_comment = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    private TextView textView_item = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    private EditText editText_comment = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    private EditText editText_item = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    List_v2 list = new List_v2();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void ButtonOnClick(View view) {
        list.item = editText_item.getText().toString();
        list.comment = editText_comment.getText().toString();
        textView_comment.setText(list.comment);
        textView_item.setText(list.item);
    }
}
```

Код класса:

```
package com.example.classes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List_v2 extends ArrayList {
    public String item;
    public String comment;
}
```

Расположение файлов:
[image: Расположение файлов]

Логи:

```
2020-01-25 19:48:09.327 11086-11086/com.example.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 11086
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.example.test.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831
```

Comment: Если падает, значит есть логи. Если есть логи, значит нужно их показать.

Comment: Может быть, стоит инициализацию view делать в onCreate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя искать вьюхи в разметке, пока разметка не загружена. А она загружается в `onCreate()` методе. Который, как и все методы, может быть вызван только после инициализации класса, в процессе которой инициализируются переменные класса, где вы и пытаетесь искать в разметке через `findViewById`.

Вам надо перенести вызовы `findViewById()` в метод `onCreate()`, поместив их после `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

---

Также надо заметить, что класс `List_v2` - написан неправильно. Именовать через подчёркивания не следует. Как и не нужно в вашем случае наследовать `ArrayList`